# How to view property value in debugger

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, debugging

I have a UIViewController and would like to see properties such as myview.view.hidden.  In another class where I declare an instance of UIViewController, I can assign and read the property through code but would like to know the value at various points.  In the debugger console, I can't do "po myview.view.hidden" or "p myview.view.hidden".  Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
po [[myview view] hidden]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I get this message, "Target does not respond to this message selector."

Comment: Start with "po myview". Then "po [myview view]". Then "po [[myview view] hidden]". You will discover this way which class is incorrect. Note that an object called "myview" should almost certainly not have a method called "view." Is "myview" the view controller? Don't abbreviate "view controller" to "view". It will create a lot of confusion in your code. Call it a view controller, a controller, or even a "vc" if you must. But don't confuse your views and your view controllers. This may be why you're getting this error; if "myview" is actually a view.